# how to efficiently force columns shared by multiple data frames to be of the same class type

Tags: r

I found the following function on this website and it works great when I'm only trying to match the data types of the second data frame to the first. 
But what happens if I have more than 10 data frames, and the same columns shared across them are of different data types, such as the column "grade" in one data frame is classified as numeric and in several others is classified as character?  Can this function be modified so that all I have to do is specify which data frames that go into the function and have it return multiple data frames with data types that match the first? I don't have any experience with functions but I hope to learn more about them. I've been using the matchColClasses (thank you GGAnderson for this!) but with two data frames at a time and it can be a bit laborious. Thanks for any feedback you provide.

```
 matchColClasses<- function(df1, df2){
# Purpose:  protect joins from column type mismatches - a problem with multi-column empty df          
# Input:    df1 - master for class assignments, df2 - for col reclass and return.
# Output:   df2 with shared columns classed to match df1
# Usage:    df2 <- matchColClasses(df1, df2)

  sharedColNames <- names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]
  sharedColTypes <- sapply(df1[,sharedColNames], class)

  for (n in sharedColNames) {
    class(df2[, n]) <- sharedColTypes[n]
  }

  return(df2)
 }
```

Comment: I think the simplest solution to this problem is to define correct column classes when the datasets are read into R.

Comment: Oh I see.  I will certainly try it next.  Thank you for your advice!